# enum vs enum34 in Python 3.7 causing pyinstaller errors

Tags: python, enums, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I tried running PyInstaller to create a simple executable, but it generated errors which other posts here suggest its an enum vs enum34 issue. I am running Python 3.7 and for some odd reason my installation has only enum34 (1.1.6).
I am NOT an IT guy, but I am the sole programmer for a startup and am terrified of breaking my environment and not being able to fix it.
Is the proper procedure to simply install enum (I understand it may overwrite enum34), or uninstall enum34, then install enum?
I've also seen posts where folks had difficulties deleting enum34. Any hints on how to avoid those?

Comment: The `enum` module was made part of the Python standard library in version 3.4, so you should have to install anything for Python 3.7. I would suggest uninstalling whatever is installed. You may have to reinstall Python 3.7 (or repair it if the installer provides that option) afterwards — but the goal should be to create a standard environment for your development. There *are* differences between the separately installed `enum` and what's in version 3.4, so you might have to fix some code to work with the latter. If you're scared of breaking things, make a backup beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. I just uninstalled enum34(using pip uninstall enum34) and then ran pyinstaller in the terminal and everything seemed to be working

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a old post, but just adding my experience.. I had the same issue on a Win10 system.

Trying to run pyinstaller, I got the error "The 'enum34' package is an obsolete backport of a standard library package and is incompatible with PyInstaller. Please `pip uninstall enum34` then try again."

So I uninstalled enum34 (Had to do it as system administrator) and try running the pyisntaller.. and it worked.  Very strange that this would be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

For the record:

- `enum` on PyPI -- preexisting third-party enum library
- `enum34` on PyPI -- backport of the 3.4 stdlib enum
- `aenum` on PyPI -- advanced enum library compatible with the stdlib version, and maintained by the same fellow (me)
- `enum` in the stdlib -- this was added in version 3.4 and has been a part of Python ever since.

--

Sadly, I don't know how to solve your problem.